# Receiving signal SIGABRT error for simple struct

Tags: swift, struct

I am receiving an error: Execution was interrupted, reason: signal SIGABRT

```
import Cocoa

struct Game {
        var score = 0 {
                didSet {
                        print(“Score is now \(game.score)”)
                }
        }
}

var game = Game()
game.score += 10 // this is the line I receive error
game.score -= 3
game.score += 1

print(game.score)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the `print` in `didSet`. You should not be trying to access external variables like that. Just print `self.score` or just `score`.

```swift
struct Game {
    var score = 0 {
        didSet {
            print("Score is now \(score)")
        }
    }
}
```